# How to implement a counter with CloudKit?

Tags: cloudkit

## Situation

I want to manage a counter (the number of times of button is pressed) with `CloudKit`.

Each time a user press a button, I want to increment an integer. This integer will hence be a global (for all users) counter of how many times the button has been pressed.

## Question

Is there a preferred way to do it?

### My idea

I could store a `CKRecord` with this number and fetch and modify it each time the button is pressed. But, isn't it unsafe since it might be updated by many people (more or less) at the same time?

Comment: A counter for what? Why CloudKit? What's the scope and use of this counter? Your current question is really unclear.

Comment: @rmaddy CloudKit is the technology I have chosen for the back-end side. I tried to make my question clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea would work. When doing an update you will first fetch the counter record, increment the counter and then save it back. If another user has updated the counter in the mean time, then CloudKit will give you an error and you can try it again.

But it does depend on how often users will press the button. If you have multiple pushes per second during a longer period, then you will probably get a lot of errors when updating the data. The time before an update succeeds will grow.